# Как на сайте по нажатию кнопки скопировать содержимое DIV  в буфер обмена

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, html5

Собственно, есть DIV. В нем есть динамический текст. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки содержимое копировалось в буфер обмена.
Спасибо!

Comment: На lamoda, например, как я понял, это реализовано через flash. Если что-нибудь понимаете в этой технологии, поизучайте. Интересная фича.

Answer (score 3):

Автоматическое копирование в буфер обмена связано с дополнительными рисками, поэтому большинство нормальных браузеров блокируют эту возможность. Политика безопасности...
Лично я в такой ситуации использую следующий трюк:

```
function copyToClipboard (text) {
    window.prompt ("Чтобы скопировать текст в буфер обмена, нажмите Ctrl+C и Enter", text);
}
```

Пользователь получает вопросительное окно, в котором весь текст для копирования уже выделен. Осталось только нажать Ctrl+C и Enter (чтобы закрыть окно). Эта операция полностью безопасна, поскольку пользователь производит копирование в буфер самостоятельно. И, конечно, метод работает во всех браузерах.

Comment: будьте добры, напишите полный код, пожалуйста.
- подойдет ли это именно для DIV ?
- name у ДИВ = "text"  я правильно понимаю?
- какое ограничение на колво символов? потому что у меня оно действительно большое

Comment: то же самое советуют на [stackoverflow][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Не блокируют. http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard